# How can I order posts by Name - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm ordering the posts in my model History by the attribute Title like this:

```
def index
  @histories = History.all(:order => 'title')
end
```

I have the following post titles:

- Post 1
- Post 2
- Post 11

The problem I have is that 'Post 11' appears before 'Post 2'. How can I make sure that the posts are ordered correctly? (I want Post 2 to appear before Post 11).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I assumed this format of title is conventional in your models.

First I would add this method to the History model:

```
def numerized_title
  return 0 unless title.present?
  Integer(title.tr('^0-9',''))
end
```

Then in the controller:

```
@histories = History.all.sort_by(&:numerized_title)
```

Instead of trying with some nasty mysql you can just use this in the application and you can TEST it out for every kind of `title` if its working.

Keep in mind `Integer(str)` will raise an Exception if it's not able to generate a `Fixnum`.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it, but I think the following should work.

```
def index
  @histories = History.all(:order => 'REPLACE(title,"Post","")+0 ASC')
end


mysql> desc z;
+------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| a     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select * from z;
+---------+
| a       |
+---------+
| post 1  |
| post 11 |
| post 2  |
+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)



mysql> select * from z order by a asc;
+---------+
| a       |
+---------+
| post 1  |
| post 11 |
| post 2  |
+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

  mysql> select * from z order by REPLACE(a,"post","")+0 ASC;
+---------+
| a       |
+---------+
| post 1  |
| post 2  |
| post 11 |
+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: The only problem with this code is that Post 1 shows up after Post 2

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASC or DESC option after the field

```
def index
  @histories = History.all(:order => 'title ASC')
end
```